# passing variable in shell_exec

Tags: php, bash

I have a problem with passing a variable form the link to message in discord bash script. I tried several options like adding variable .$sale. etc but nothing worked. Anyone could point me what can I do to make it work?

```
$sale = $_GET['sale'];

echo shell_exec('/bin/bash discord.sh --webhook-url=https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xxx/x123 --text "New sale just arrived from" '.$sale.' --footer "Info" --timestamp');
?>
```

Comment: Probably move the double-quote `"New sale just arrived from '.$sale.'"`

Comment: I've tried it too but it's completely crashing the whole script and giving me error 500

Comment: Who knows what's in sale? Does the command work in the command line? https://3v4l.org/5Fntj

Comment: Your approach would break, if `$sale` contains a space or a newline character or other characters with special meaning to bash (for instance, a `$`). If you can exclude this possibility, I suggest that - for debugging - you put a `set -x` as the first statemant in `discord.sh` and investigate what gets printed on stderr.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it is the right way to inject variables in the command line.

But it is sensible to attacks as you didnt sanitize the variable.

We can't really help you more since you didnt provided the error details.

as AbraCadaver said you may want to group your text parameter as one variable and escape it to avoid attacks.

```
<?php
$sale = $_GET['sale'];
$text = escapeshellarg("New sale just arrived from $sale");

echo shell_exec('/bin/bash discord.sh --webhook-url=https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xxx/x123 --text '.$text.' --footer "Info" --timestamp');
?>
```

Comment: why the downvote ? can you give some feedbacks ?

Comment: Maybe because you didn't actually explain what the problem was? Your advice is correct though, always use `escapeshellarg()`

Comment: he needs to group the text parameter as one variable and escape it.

Answer (score 0):

The close double quote must be at the end of the `--text` option:

```
shell_exec('/bin/bash discord.sh --webhook-url=https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xxx/x123 --text "New sale just arrived from '.$sale.'" --footer "Info" --timestamp');
```

Comment: " must be at the end of --text option